# Contiki with redwire econotags: make: *** No rule to make target `hello-world.upload'. Stop

Tags: makefile, contiki

I have bought a few redwire econotags r3 in order to use them with Instant Contiki. As a newbie i followed the manual: http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html. However when i'm trying to upload a program to the motes i receive an error. For example for hello-world:

```
cd contiki/examples/hello-world
make TARGET=redbee-econotag hello-world
make TARGET=redbee-econotag hello-world.upload
```

and I receive:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `hello-world.upload'.  Stop.
```

I'm searching the last two days but i can't understand what's the problem. I can see through the Virtual Machine menu in VMWare Player that the mote is connected correctly to the USB port. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tools to load econotags is not currently integrated with the Contiki 'make upload' command.

To load code on to econotags, please see the [libmc1322x documentation](https://github.com/malvira/libmc1322x/wiki). Specifically:

```
https://github.com/malvira/libmc1322x/wiki/libmc1322x
```

Typically you use `mc1322x-load` to load the code into RAM via the UART 1 bootloader (usually /dev/ttyUSB1). Such as:

```
mc1322x-load -f rftest-tx_redbee-econotag.bin -t /dev/ttyUSB1
```

You then reset the econotag to activate the bootloader.

To program the flash, you need `flasher.bin` from [libmc1322x](https://github.com/malvira/libmc1322x/). And then you do:

```
mc1322x-load -f flasher_redbee-econotag.bin -s blink-red_redbee-econotag.bin -t /dev/ttyUSB1
```

You can also use `bbmc` to reset and erase the econotag from the command line. See https://github.com/malvira/libmc1322x/wiki/bbmc